# JS onKeyup Counter - How to change the color of the counter when he turns negative?

Tags: javascript, colors

```js
$(function(){

        function limitaCaracteres(input, counter, limit){
          $('.'+counter).text(limit+' restantes');
          var left;
          $('.'+input).on('keyup', function(e){
            var qtdCaracteres = $(this).val().length;
            left = limit-qtdCaracteres;
            $('.'+counter).text(left+' restantes');

          });
        }
        limitaCaracteres('text1', 'count1', 10);
      });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #EAEAEA;">
      <input type="text" name="title" class="input100 text1" autocomplete="off" required>     
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Title"></span>
      <span class="count1"></span>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to change the color of the counter, initially the color should be green, and when the counter turns negative, the color should be red.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `if(counter < 0)`, change css color property to red, other wise green ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Could you give me more information please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as follow:

```js
    $(function(){

function limitaCaracteres(input, counter, limit){
  $('.'+counter).text(limit+' restantes');
  var left;
  $('.'+input).on('keyup', function(e){
    var qtdCaracteres = $(this).val().length;
    left = limit-qtdCaracteres;
   
    $('.'+counter).text(left+' restantes');
    if(left<0){
        $('.'+counter).removeClass("positive");
        $('.'+counter).addClass("negative");
    }else{
        $('.'+counter).removeClass("negative");
        $('.'+counter).addClass("positive");
    }

  });
}
limitaCaracteres('text1', 'count1', 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .negative{
        color: red;
    }
    .positive{
        color: greenyellow;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #EAEAEA;">
      <input type="text" name="title" class="input100 text1" autocomplete="off" required>     
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Title"></span>
      <span class="count1 positive"></span>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
```